# Why categories relation with products disappear when I update products in Opencart?

Tags: php, import, opencart, opencart-3, opencart-module

I'm developing an extension in Opencart when I try updating existing products with a relationship to some categories, the products get uncategorized and leave their categories although I disabled all kinds of categorizing in product importing or updating.

Here a snippet of product import & update function:

```
    public function format_product( $product, $update = false, $force_update = false ){
    if( empty( $product ) ){
        return $product;
    }

    if( !$update || $force_update ){

        $temp = array(
            'product_description' => array(),
            'model'             => isset( $product->sku ) ? $product->sku : '',
            'sku'               => isset( $product->sku ) ? $product->sku : '',
            'upc'               => '',
            'ean'               => '',
            'jan'               => '',
            'isbn'              => '',
            'mpn'               => '',
            'location'          => '',
            'price'             => '0',
            'points'            => '',
            'tax_class_id'      => '0',
            'quantity'          => '0',
            'minimum'           => '1',
            'subtract'          => '1',
            'stock_status_id'   => '5',
            'shipping'          => '1',
            'date_available'    => date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( '-1 day') ),
            'length'            => '',
            'width'             => '',
            'height'            => '',
            'length_class_id'   => '1',
            'weight'            => '',
            'weight_class_id'   => '1',
            'status'            => '1',
            'sort_order'        => '0',
            'manufacturer'      => '',
            'manufacturer_id'   => '0',
            'product_store'     => array(0),
            // 'product_category'  => array(),
            'product_option'    => array(),
            'image'             => ''  // This is Pending.
        );

        //  Add to selected stores.
        if ( !empty( $this->all_stores ) ) {
            $temp['product_store'] = $this->all_stores;
        }

        $languageCodes = array();
        foreach ( $this->languages as $key => $lng ) {
            // Check for name in current language.
            $lng_code = explode( '-', $lng['code'] );
            $lng_code = $lng_code[0];

            $name = $product->name;
            $description = $product->description;

            /*$product_name = array_key_exists( $lng_code, $name ) ? $name[$lng_code] : $name['en'];
            $product_desc = array_key_exists( $lng_code, $description ) ? $description[$lng_code] : $description['en'];*/
            $product_name = isset( $name->$lng_code ) ? $name->$lng_code : '';
            if( empty( $product_name )){
              $product_name = isset( $name->en ) ? $name->en : '';
          }
          /*set url*/
         if(version_compare(VERSION, '3.0.0','<') ) {
            if(isset($name->en)){
                $urlData = $name->en;
            }elseif (isset($name->$lng_code)) {
                $urlData = $name->en;
            }
            if(!empty($urlData)){
                $url = strtolower($urlData);
                $urlKey = str_replace(' ', '-', $url); 
                $temp['keyword'] = $urlKey;
            }
          }
          /*set url*/
          $product_desc = isset( $description->$lng_code ) ? $description->$lng_code : '';
          if( empty( $product_desc )){
              $product_desc = isset( $description->en ) ? $description->en : '';
          }
          $temp['product_description'][$lng['language_id']] = array(
            'name'              => $product_name,
            'description'       => $product_desc,
            'meta_title'        => $product_name,
            'meta_description'  => '',
            'meta_keyword'      => '',
            'tag'               => '',
        );
          $languageCodes[] = $lng_code;
          $languageIds[$lng_code] = $lng['language_id'];

      }
      /*attribute group code*/
      if(!empty($languageCodes)){
        $language_code = $languageCodes[0];
        $attributeGrouplanguageId = $languageIds[$language_code];
    }
    /*load model*/
    if( $this->is_admin ){
        $this->load->model('catalog/attribute_group');
    }else{
        $admin_dir = str_replace( 'system/', 'admin/', DIR_SYSTEM );
        require_once $admin_dir . "model/catalog/attribute_group.php";
        $this->model_catalog_attribute_group = new ModelCatalogAttributeGroup( $this->registry );
    }
    /*load model*/
    $attribute_group_id = $this->model_extension_module_knawat_dropshipping->getAttributeGroup('knawat');
    if(!$attribute_group_id){
        /*add attribute set*/
        $attributeGroupArray = array();
        $attributeGroupArray['sort_order'] = 2;
        $attributeGroupArray['attribute_group_description'][$attributeGrouplanguageId] = array(
            'name'              => 'Knawat'
        );
        $attribute_group_id = $this->model_catalog_attribute_group->addAttributeGroup($attributeGroupArray); 
    }
    /*add attribute set*/
    /*attribute group code*/
    /*load model*/
    if( $this->is_admin ){
        $this->load->model('catalog/attribute');
    }else{
        $admin_dir = str_replace( 'system/', 'admin/', DIR_SYSTEM );
        require_once $admin_dir . "model/catalog/attribute.php";
        $this->model_catalog_attribute = new ModelCatalogAttribute( $this->registry );
    }
    /*load model*/
    /*variation array*/
    if (isset($product->variations[0]->attributes) && !empty($product->variations[0]->attributes)) {
        $attribute = $product->variations[0]->attributes;
        if($attribute[0]){
            if (isset($attribute[0]->name) || !empty($attribute[0]->name) ) {
                $variationdata = (array)$attribute[0]->name;
            }
        }
    }
    /*variation array*/
    /*attribute code*/
    if (isset($product->attributes) && !empty($product->attributes)) {
        $subArray = array();
        foreach ($product->attributes as $key => $attribute) {
            $attributeNames =  (array)$attribute->name;
                foreach ($attributeNames as $key => $value) {
                if(!empty($variationdata[$key]) && !in_array($variationdata[$key], $attributeNames)){
                    if(in_array($key, $languageCodes)){
                        $attributeId = $this->model_extension_module_knawat_dropshipping->getAttributeData($value);
                        if(!$attributeId){
                            $languageId = $languageIds[$key];
                            $newArray[$languageId] = array(
                                'language_id' => $languageId,
                                'name'  => $value
                            );
                        }               
                    } 
                }

                }
                if(!empty($newArray)){
                    $subArray['attribute_group_id'] = $attribute_group_id;
                    $subArray['sort_order'] = 2;
                    $subArray['attribute_description'] = $newArray; 
                    $this->model_catalog_attribute->addAttribute($subArray);         
                }
        }
    }
    /*attribute code*/
    /*product code*/
   if(!empty($product->attributes)){
    foreach ($product->attributes as $key => $attribute) {
        $attributeNames =  (array)$attribute->name;
        if($variationdata != $attributeNames){
            $productAttributes = array();
            foreach ($attributeNames as $key => $value) {
                if(in_array($key, $languageCodes)){
                    $languageId = $languageIds[$key];
                    if(isset($attribute->options[0]->$key)){
                        $options = $attribute->options[0]->$key;
                    }else{
                        if(isset($attribute->options[0]->en)){
                            $options = $attribute->options[0]->en;
                        }else if (isset($attribute->options[0]->ar)) {
                            $options = $attribute->options[0]->ar;
                        }else if (isset($attribute->options[0]->tr)){
                            $options = $attribute->options[0]->tr;
                        }
                    }
                    $attributeId = $this->model_extension_module_knawat_dropshipping->getAttributeData($value);
                    $productAttributes[$languageId] = array(
                        'text' => $options
                    );
                    $attributeId = (int) $attributeId;
                    $temp['product_attribute'][] = array(
                        'attribute_id'  => $attributeId,
                        'product_attribute_description' => $productAttributes
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
    /*product code end*/

        /**
         * Setup Product Category.
         */
        //make products get uncategorized in both import and update.

        // if( isset( $product->categories ) && !empty( $product->categories ) ) {
        //     $new_cats = array();
        //     foreach ( $product->categories as $category ) {
        //         if( isset( $category->name ) && !empty( $category->name ) ){
        //             $new_cats[] = (array)$category->name;
        //         }
        //     }
        //     $temp['product_category'] = $this->model_extension_module_knawat_dropshipping->parse_categories( $new_cats );
        // }

        /**
         * Setup Product Images.
         */
        if( isset( $product->images ) && !empty( $product->images ) ) {
            $images = (array)$product->images;
            $product_sku = isset( $product->sku ) ? $product->sku : '';

            $product_images = $this->parse_product_images( $images, $product_sku );
            if( !empty( $product_images ) ){
                $temp['image'] = $product_images[0];
                unset( $product_images[0] );
                if( count( $product_images ) > 0 ){
                    foreach ($product_images as $pimage ) {
                        $temp_image['image'] = $pimage;
                        $temp_image['sort_order'] = '0';
                        $temp['product_image'][] = $temp_image;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }else{
        $temp = array();
    }

    if( isset( $product->variations ) && !empty( $product->variations ) ){
        $quantity = 0;
        $price = $product->variations[0]->sale_price;
        if( isset( $product->variations[0]->market_price ) ){
            $market_price = $product->variations[0]->market_price;
        }
        if( empty( $market_price ) ){
            $market_price = $price;
        }
        foreach ( $product->variations as $vvalue ) {
            $quantity += $vvalue->quantity;
        }
        if(isset($product->variations[0]->weight)){
            $weight = $product->variations[0]->weight;
            $temp['weight']     = $weight;
        }
        $temp['price']      = $market_price;
        $temp['quantity']   = $quantity;
        if( $quantity > 0 ){
            $temp['stock_status_id'] = '7';
        }else{
            $temp['stock_status_id'] = '5';
        }
        if(!empty($price)){
            if($price < $market_price){
                $temp['product_special'][] = array(
                    'customer_group_id' => 1,
                    'price'  => $price,
                    'priority' => 1,
                    'date_start' => 0000-00-00,
                    'date_end' => 0000-00-00
                );    
            }
        }
        $temp['product_option'] = $this->model_extension_module_knawat_dropshipping->parse_product_options( $product->variations, $price,$update );
    }
    if(!empty($temp['product_option'])){
        foreach ($temp['product_option'] as $key) {
            $i = 0;
                if(isset($key['product_option_value'])){
                    $j = count($key['product_option_value']);
                }else{
                    $j = 0;
                }
                foreach ($key['product_option_value'] as $value) {
                    if($value['quantity'] == 0){
                        $i++;
                    }
                }
            }
            if($i == $j){
                $temp['stock_status_id'] = '5';
            }
    }
    if(empty($temp['product_option']) && !$update){
         $this->log->write("Product Failed , It's variations not available or available with zero quantity, Sku : ".$temp['sku']);
            return false;
    }
    ///////////////////////////////////
    /////// @TODO Custom Fields ///////
    ///////////////////////////////////
    error_log("Orginal Product: " . json_encode($product));
    error_log("temp Product: " . json_encode($temp));
    return $temp;
}
```

If anyone can help me with this problem. Thank you

Comment: Your code doesn't show any use of the OpenCart catalog category models. The only category related code seems to be commented. More information is needed to help you to debug this. Please provide all of the code if you can.

Comment: You can check the code in Github here: https://github.com/hamusthekiller/knawat-dropshipping-opencart
but, this is the most important part of the product importing and updating.
I disabled adding categories in product import and update to make products keep their categories but what I see when I test is that products' relations disappear when I update them.

Comment: @RoAchterberg can u still help me with this issue?

Comment: @MohamedElsayed we're happy to help but on second read of this question and having a quick look at the repo on GitHub, I have to be honest and say I don't know what the problem is. Your question isn't very clear and despite the available code, I have no idea what the problem is. Can you take some time to rewrite the question itself? What is the "relationship to some categories" where is this relationship? What do you mean by "leave their categories"? Also, I have no idea what this means "I disabled all kinds of categorizing in product importing" Please try be a little more clear and we'll help

Comment: @Daniel Well, I reached a conclusion that Opencart editProduct in catalogModel class when get called, it destroys every realation_id_to_category of every product and also happens with attributes, options and, variants then begins updating products according to the Opencart update scheme. I will have to find a workaround, unfortunately.

Comment: Perhaps you can use an OCMOD to override that default behaviour if there is no data supplied? It seems to delete all relationships and then add them, assuming that there are new relationships to implement. If you added a condition `if (isset($data['product_category']))` before the deletion, it might prevent this behaviour

Comment: @Daniel I guess that will be the solution to override the editData function in OC and add the condition u mentioned. Thanks for the help. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to this question is as follows:

`editProduct` function in `CatalogModel` class in Opencart removes all `relation_id_to_category` before beginning to modify an existing product, so in order to not make the attached categories in a product be removed you should comment out this line of code and everything as it should but it may affect other modules working in Opencart so do it at your own risk.